# Where in the kernel /dev/kmsg gets initialized?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, linux-kernel, dmesg

I'm trying to figure out at which point in the boot up process `/dev/kmsg` gets initialized and can thus be written. On my system the first line that occurs in dmesg is `printk(KERN_INFO "Initializing cgroup subsys %s\n", ss->name);` from `kernel/cgroup.c`. I tried to trace backwards and search the kernel but I didn't find the function where `/dev/kmsg` is beeing initialized.

Does somebody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/dev/kmsg` represeted by the `kmsg_fops` structure which has `file_operations` type that represents standard operations with a file:

```
const struct file_operations kmsg_fops = {
    .open = devkmsg_open,
    .read = devkmsg_read,
    .write_iter = devkmsg_write,
    .llseek = devkmsg_llseek,
    .poll = devkmsg_poll,
    .release = devkmsg_release,
};
```

You can find definition of the `kmsg_fops` and related operations in the [printk.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L792). Its initialization and initialization of other virtual devices as `/dev/zero`, `/dev/null` is in the [chr_dev_init](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L843) function.

This function called during Linux kernel initialization process, after the kernel booted and decompressed. Note that after the `chr_dev_init` function, the:

```
fs_initcall(chr_dev_init);
```

macro that expands to the `__define_initcall` macro:

```
#define fs_initcall(fn)         __define_initcall(fn, 5)
```

two parameters: function which will initialize char device and `initcall` level, where `5` is `fs`:

```
static char *initcall_level_names[] __initdata = {
    "early",
    "core",
    "postcore",
    "arch",
    "subsys",
    "fs",
    "device",
    "late",
};
```

The `__define_initcall` macro expands to the [initcall](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h#L193) definition which will be called in the `do_initcalls` from the [init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c)

Comment: But where is it called during boot process? Can't find it anywhere in `/arch/x86` or `init`?

Comment: I've update my answer, and I think that it is enough :)

Comment: Okay now I understand why I didn't find it. Thanks a lot!